# Intercept window.open from an iframe within a UIWebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iframe, uiwebview

In my iOS app, I have a `UIWebView` configured such that any link clicked will open a separate screen with the intended url.

I do this by monitoring `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` and opening a new view controller when `navigationType` is `UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked`.

Occasionally, there will be an embedded iframe within this `UIWebView`, which calls `window.open(url)`. When this happens, the content inside my `UIWebView` gets replaced with the content from the opened url.

In this case, `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` is called and `navigationType` is set to `UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther` - which is the same `navigationType` that I see when an iframe loads.

How do I differentiate between an iframe calling `window.open(url)`, and an iframe just loading?